# Nodejs certificate error while trying to create https server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I created an ssl certificate automatically with Let's Encrypt.

Now I'm trying to use them to create a https server with node.js

```
var https = require("https");

global.fs = require("fs");

var certContent = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/csr/0000_csr-certbot.pem", "utf8");
var keysContent = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-certbot.pem", "utf8");

console.log("Cert content:", certContent, keysContent);

var server = https.createServer(
{
    cert:certContent,
    key: keysContent
}, 
function(request, response)
{
    
});
```

On the create server call, it gives this error:

```
_tls_common.js:109
      c.context.setCert(cert);
                ^

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:109:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:853:25)
    at new Server (https.js:60:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:81:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/foo/public_html/main.js:167:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
```

The console log shows this output:

```
Cert content:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
// base64 here
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
// base64 here
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Why is it saying that the pem files are invalid when they have the correct header and footer?

Comment: the issue is might be with copy-paste of certs or key... try again adding the certs and key

Comment: @aRvi not sure what you mean by that. Edit: I copied the output from the console into two new text files, but it has the same issue.

Comment: this error occurs when the certs or the key files are incorrect... remove old creds and add again `/etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-certbot.pem`, `/etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_csr-certbot.pem`

Comment: @aRvi I think they need to be converted from pem files to another format instead

Answer (score 1):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
// base64 here
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

You are only providing a **certificate request** here. But it is expected that you actually provide the **certificate**, which will look like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The certificates are probably somewhere below `/etc/letsencrypt/live`.

Comment: In the /etc/letsencrypt directory, it contains these files and folders:  accounts/  csr/  keys/  options-ssl-apache.conf  renewal/  renewal-hooks/  .updated-options-ssl-apache-conf-digest.txt, I found the pem files in the csr and keys folder and I have not seen any other pem files.

Comment: @John: I have no idea where the certificate is then located which you claim to have created. Maybe you didn't actually create a certificate but only the certificate request and key?

Comment: I'll try to create another one then

Answer (score 0):

After following aRvi and Steffen advice, I attempted to recreate the ssl certificates.

It turns out that it was failing to create them due to an error in the apache plugin for certbot.

It was trying to use a folder name that didn't exist:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/httpd/conf.d/le_http_01_challenge_pre.conf'
```

So I told it the correct folder to use with this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto certonly --apache --apache-challenge-location /etc/httpd/conf
```

I was getting this error:

```
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: ––apache-challenge-location /etc/httpd/conf
```

Because the two dashes in front of apache are the wrong dash character since I copied it off a user written blog that changed it incorrectly.